# Getting the codes of the colours instead of the actual colours in python

Tags: python

It seems like I have a problem with the (pystyle) module in Python.
See I use the next code:

```py
from pystyle import *
Write.Print("hello world",Colors.blue_to_cyan,interval=0.1)
```

so when it comes to the output, i get the CODES of The Colors NOT the exact colors
like this:

```
←[38;2;0;20;255mh←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;40;255me←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;60;255m
l←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;80;255ml←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;100;255mo←[38;2;255;255
;255m←[38;2;0;120;255m ←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;120;255mw←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;
140;255mo←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;160;255mr←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;180;255ml←[38;
2;255;255;255m←[38;2;0;200;255md←[38;2;255;255;255m←[38;2;255;255;255mPS
```

so if you can help me that would be great
{{ i'll send an image to be clearer too }}

THANKS!!

> [THE IMAGE OF THE CODE AND OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfmGv.png)

I wanted typewriter effect with colors in my output, but instead, I got the codes of the colors not the exact colors.

Comment: So what did you expect? The codes of the colors is an easy digital representation of what the colors are, and can be used in lots of programs to make the colors you would expect.

Comment: i see your point, but what i'm asking is how to show the colors not the codes of the colors

Comment: I ran your code in vscode and got the output you wanted: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rV5m.png)

Comment: I see, have you tried using a different terminal? If that doesn't work, then it may be another issue such as [this from the github of the pacakge](https://github.com/billythegoat356/pystyle/issues/10)

Comment: oh ...ok ..yeah ..that must be it ....maybe I should upgrade my windows version....thank you so much